# How to set required true in textarea in jquery

Tags: text, textarea

$('#sitrcpdevdetremarks').prop("required", true);

This not working please help me how to set required true in textarea

Comment: share your html please. Or better yet make a stack snippet that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: if ($('#sitrcpdevdetremarks').length) {
                $('#sitrcpdevdetremarks').prop("required", true);
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided code should work fine (given appropriate HTML).

See this example, on modern browsers the `<textarea>` is required and will not allow submit if it's empty:

```js
$('#sitrcpdevdetremarks').prop("required", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="sitrcpdevdetremarks"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```